# Change in an List apply change to the other list

Tags: android, list

> When i change some value in index(any entry) of entries Array . it change in my emptyEntries . Why this reference issue comes. I am adding values with addALL

```
List<Answer> emptyEntries = new ArrayList<Answer>();

emptyEntries .addAll(reviewInProgress.getCategories().get(categoryIndex).getAnswers().get(questionIndex).getQuestion().getGroupAnswers());

Log.v("questionIndex", " " +questionIndex);

reviewInProgress.getCategories().get(categoryIndex).getAnswers().get(questionIndex)
                                .getQuestion().getEntries().add(emptyEntries );
```

I want to add emptyEntries on click of a button. But i don't want to depict change in getGroupAnswer. Can someOne explain what am i doing wrong.

**Why there is a change in below answer Array** where i don't change them any where ??

```
reviewInProgress.getCategories().get(categoryIndex).getAnswers().get(questionIndex).getQuestion().getGroupAnswers()
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, then it is because you are adding same object to 2 lists, and when you change the object's fields, it will change in the object, and the object is in 2 lists.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear.. which line causes the unexpected change? What kind of change is that? The code you showed doesn't make any changes to the entries, it only adds them to different lists. So far I can tell that you are adding same objects of group answers to emptyEntries. Thus, if you change an object in emptyEntries, it will be updated in group answers too. If this is not what you were asking, please provide more info. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to add it using a copy of it by using addAll

Comment: `addall` is not going to create a copy of each object. There in general is no way to automatically create a copy of any object in Java.